# How to pass an environment variable as a command line parameter in Run/Debug configuration in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables

I am trying to learn PyCharm, need to pass an environment variable as a command line parameter to my process, e.g. execute an equivalent of `myScript.py -u $myVar` on Linux, or `myScript.py -u %myVar%` on Windows.

How do I specify that in the PyCharm configuration? I don't want my script to depend on the name `myVar`, just on the content of that environment variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in PyCharm Run/Debug configuration
for "Script Parameters:"
Enter

```
-u ${myVar}
```

*Note: This will work only for existing env. variables but not for env. variables that you set up in the PyCharm Run/Debug configuration. For that to work, you will need to look into "Before Launch" configuration*

Comment: I think *Before Launch* is being run in a separate process so it's of no use as far as setting environment variables is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to define new env vars for passing them to Run/Debug configuration (as suggested by @alok-a), even if defining them on a script executed in "Before Launch". For notice, I'm using PyCharm 2018.3.4.

The workaround that works for me is to create a python script that prepare the full command line and calls it using the subprocess module.

```py
import subprocess

# Build params line

cmd = ["python", script_path] + params.split()

subprocess.run(cmd)
```

Set your breakpoints in the target script (the one indicated by script_path).

Run the newly created wrapper script and have a happy debugging. Not a charming solution, but it works at least.

Answer (score -4):

Go to Edit configurations > Environment variables. Add or edit.[image]

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I was not interested in *setting* an evironment variable for the duration of the run. Rather, I need to *pass its value* as a run time parameter, as shown in the question. How does adding it to that list help?

Comment: I also would like this question answered.  It'd be extremely helpful when trying to debug Horizon tests.

Comment: @woodm1979 see another answer here