# How do I pass an environment variable to Parameters in PyCharm's Run/Debug configurations?

Tags: pycharm

The parameters that I need to pass to my Python program use some environment variables.

#### Example:

This is how I run it on the terminal:

```
export BUCKET="/tmp/bucket"
python main.py --input $BUCKET/input --output $BUCKET/output
```

On PyCharm, I created a Run/Debug configuration with an environment variable called `BUCKET` and passed the following string as parameters: `--input $BUCKET/input --output $BUCKET/output`.

When PyCharm executes the program, it doesn't pick up the value of `BUCKET` as `/tmp/bucket`. It considers `$BUCKET` to be a string.

I also tried using `${BUCKET}` instead of `$BUCKET` but that doesn't work either.

Is there some way to pass variables?

**Note**: The reason I want to do this is that I have a large number of parameters in my real code. I have only provided a toy example above. I want to be able to update an environment variable only in one place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an environment variable as a command line parameter in Run/Debug configuration in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663475/how-to-pass-an-environment-variable-as-a-command-line-parameter-in-run-debug-con)

Comment: You may want to see my answer on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713319/environment-variables-not-evaluated-in-program-parameters-in-windows-pycharm/66234249#66234249

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem a few days back. I found a plugin called [EnvFile](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile). 
[image: EnvFile]
Using this you can have an env file exported before running the script. After installing it, you'll get an extra tab EnvFile in your configuration. Select your environment file there. It is specific to the configuration. Now, every time you run the configuration environment variables will be exported. 
[image: EnvFile Tab]
My .env file

[image: Env File]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I can print the environment variables by `print(os.environ['SOME_ENV_VAR'])`, but the env variables in script parameters are not replaced with their values (even if I've checked the "Substitute Environment ..." box). I wonder why.

Comment: This worked for me all the time. I think you would have missed something in the configuration. But I'm not sure.

Comment: For me it also does not work like this. Any solutions?