# environment variables not evaluated in program parameters in windows pycharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, environment-variables

Trying to run the wordcount.py example from the data-flow quickstart [example](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python) via pycharm, and I ran into an issue when parsing the command line arguments that contain environment variables.

[image: How I set my environment variables]

[image: |How I specified the paramaters]

When I set the environment variables and run the script in the terminal with the same paramaters it works just fine:

```
python wordcount.py --input gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt --output gs://%BUCKET%/wordcount/outputs --runner DataflowRunner --project %PROJECT% --temp_location gs://%BUCKET%/tmp/
```

I tried the following variations of parsing the environment variables - none worked: ${ENV}, $ENV$, %ENV%.

I am working on Windows 10, PyCharm version 2019.3.1.

Comment: have you tried using is like [this](https://www.techcoil.com/blog/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-your-python-application-from-pycharm/)

Comment: Yes and it works, but I tried to find a way around that... From what I saw, that feature is not supported. Oh well

Comment: Second ones are not environment variables, they are parameters to the script, please try to specify your input data as script parameters, see screenshots in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#createExplicitly

Answer (score 0):

When you pass environment variables as values for the parameters (e.g., `--project`, `--temp_location`) to Pycharm configuration, it takes those variables as "**string**" values instead of their real values which you set on the first screenshot "**User environment variables**". I did a quick search for many related threads on StackOverflow but not find a solution so I came up with my own one, that is, using your current settings and replacing the values after parsing arguments in your code:

```
# Args parsing here

if args.project == "${PROJECT}":
    args.project = os.environ.get("PROJECT")
    args.temp_location = args.temp_location.replace("${BUCKET}", os.environ.get("BUCKET"))
```

However, I think you should consider using it when

- you work with PyCharm more frequently than Terminal.
- there are many arguments referring to environment variables and you have to change their values for different settings.

Hope Pycharm will support this feature soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = (list(map(lambda x: os.environ.get(x.strip()[1:])
    if x.strip().startswith('$')
        or (x.strip().startswith('%') and x.strip().endsswith('%'))
    else x, sys.argv[1:])))
```

it will take any Run config inputs that either start with a '$' or is surrounded by '%' and attempt to resolve the environmental variable

it wil take the params passed from PyCharm.