# How to reference Environment variables set in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables

This maybe a two part question.

Background:
I'm writing a script that utilizes a tool's APIs. In order to use the API, you have to obviously authenticate. I want to store my creds in environment variables that I can reference/call in my script. I know how to set the variables in Pycharm, but I don't exactly how to reference them. I was thought to maybe set the PATH in the configurations but where exactly would the PATH be if I set the environment variables in PyCharm itself?

Question 1: Can I reference the environment variables I set in Pycharm? If so, how?
Question 2: Will this involve me setting the PATH? If so, how? (in Pycharm)

Comment: You would get those environment variables at run-time from [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) itself. Settings the variables is usually done in the [run configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55488442) - see the linked questions.

Comment: The project configuration files per se will be in the [`.idea`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-and-ide-settings.html#project_settings) folder, you can check the variables there.