# Environment variable as Command line argument

Tags: clion

Is it possible to pass environmental variable as a parameter to executable?
I tried this, but I get a string `"job_$JOB_ID"` in my app instead of `"job_123"`

[image]

**Another question that can be a workaround for me**:
Is there a way to access this config dialog parameters as a text file? So that I cen edit Program arguments in text editor instead of CLion UI. Those configs must be stored somewhere in CLion app folder

Comment: Why involve CLion at all? Can you make your target program read the environment or a text file? You will only need to pass it a path to the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to pass a `environment` variable that is defined by in run config, then it is not possible.

If you want to edit the configuration in file. Then usually it is stored in `.idea/workspace.xml`. This has all the run configurations and everything stored.

I don't have `clion` but have PyCharm, any a sample from same is

```xml
...
...
    <configuration name="scrape2" type="PythonConfigurationType" factoryName="Python" temporary="true">
      <module name="scripts" />
      <option name="INTERPRETER_OPTIONS" value="" />
      <option name="PARENT_ENVS" value="true" />
      <envs>
        <env name="PYTHONUNBUFFERED" value="1" />
      </envs>
      <option name="SDK_HOME" value="" />
      <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/deprecated" />
      <option name="IS_MODULE_SDK" value="true" />
      <option name="ADD_CONTENT_ROOTS" value="true" />
      <option name="ADD_SOURCE_ROOTS" value="true" />
      <option name="SCRIPT_NAME" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/deprecated/scrape2.py" />
      <option name="PARAMETERS" value="" />
      <option name="SHOW_COMMAND_LINE" value="false" />
      <option name="EMULATE_TERMINAL" value="false" />
      <option name="MODULE_MODE" value="false" />
      <option name="REDIRECT_INPUT" value="false" />
      <option name="INPUT_FILE" value="" />
      <method v="2" />
    </configuration>
...
```

You can see the `environment` variables are defined inside `envs`.

You can pass a externally defined environment variable using `${ENVNAME}`. See below thread on SO

[How to pass an environment variable as a command line parameter in Run/Debug configuration in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663475/how-to-pass-an-environment-variable-as-a-command-line-parameter-in-run-debug-con?rq=1)